How to apply schema markup on wordpress blog?
I recently implemented schema markup code on my website to improve its search engine visibility and enhance rich results. However, despite following the proper guidelines and embedding the code accurately, the schema markup does not seem to be functioning as expected. Instead of being processed correctly, the code is being displayed in the header section of my site. This indicates a potential issue with how the schema is integrated, possibly due to incorrect placement or syntax errors within the HTML. It's crucial to troubleshoot this problem to ensure the schema markup works effectively and boosts my site's SEO performance.
I applied schema markup to the videos, images, and entire blog on my website, aiming to enhance its SEO and visibility in search results. However, there's an issue where the schema code is displayed above the header of my site instead of being processed correctly. Despite using the correct start and end tags, the markup doesn't seem to be functioning as intended. You can see this issue for yourself on my this site. This suggests there might be a problem with how the schema is integrated or possibly a syntax error that needs to be addressed. Fixing this is essential for the schema to work properly and improve my site's performance in search engines.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

see How do I ask a good question?
